# WPF и присваивание значения из кода

Tags: c#, wpf, style

Например есть стиль в XAML:

```
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="chk_style">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Lime"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4"/>
        <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="10"/>
    </Style>
```

Как сделать так, что-бы у RadiusX/Y значение Value бралось из кода C#?

Т.е. я создаю double rad = 10; и теперь хочу присвоить Value="{StaticResource rad}", но вылетает ошибка..

Comment: из кода или из ресурса?

Comment: public partial class MainWindow : Window
    { double rad = 10;
}

Это же ресурс?)

Comment: Нет, это не ресурс

Comment: Андрей NOP, А как тогда присваивать?

Comment: В окно добавь тег `xmlns:v="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`. Потом добавь:
`<Window.Resources>
    <v:Int32 x:Key="MyInt">10</v:Int32>
</Window.Resources>`
Теперь в коде можешь ссылаться на `{StaticResource MyInt}`

Comment: «Но вылетает ошибка» — а в каком именно коде и какая именно ошибка, нам разрешается угадать самостоятельно?

Comment: John, спасибо попробую

Comment: VladD, что не находит такую переменную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать Binding.
В таком случае ваш XAML код выглядит следующим образом:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" Style="{DynamicResource chk_style}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="200"></Rectangle>

<Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="chk_style">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Fill}"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{Binding Opacity}"/>
    <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="{Binding RadiusX}"/>
    <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="{Binding RadiusY}"/>
</Style>
```

А в коде C# требуется сделать следующее:

```
  DataRect dataRect = new DataRect();
  dataRect.RadiusX = 10;
  dataRect.RadiusY = 10;
  dataRect.Opacity = 0.5;
  dataRect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
  rect.DataContext = dataRect;
```

Где DataRect объявлен как:

```
public class DataRect
{
    public double RadiusX { get; set; }
    public double RadiusY { get; set; }
    public double Opacity { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Fill { get; set; }
}
```

Конечно класс DataRect еще можно развить, добавив NotifyPropertyChanged, для динамического изменения свойств и закрыть сетеры.

rect.DataContext указывает на источник данных, а {Binding XXX} привязывает поля элемента UI / Style к полям из источника данных по их имени.

Comment: @Jefoce Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как принятый (зеленая галочка слева от ответа), если он решил ваш вопрос.